# How hide javascript on specific page

Tags: javascript, chat, smartsupp

I have a javascript code for our online chat that we use in our application. But I need this code to not appear on a specific page, eg domain/X1XY.

Can you advise me how I can write this in the main code that is called on each of our pages?

```
<!-- Smartsupp Live Chat script -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var _smartsupp = _smartsupp || {};
_smartsupp.key = '123456789';
window.smartsupp||(function(d) {
  var s,c,o=smartsupp=function(){ o._.push(arguments)};o._=[];
  s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];c=d.createElement('script');
  c.type='text/javascript';c.charset='utf-8';c.async=true;
  c.src='https://www.smartsuppchat.com/loader.js?';s.parentNode.insertBefore(c,s);
})(document);
</script>
```

Comment: We can't tell you how the CMS / build tool / template system / whatever it is you use to share code between multiple pages can be configured to exclude a piece of code from some of those pages (because we known nothing about the CMS / build tool / template system / whatever)

Answer (score 1):

If the URL of the page is unique, then you can use it to conditionally run the JavaScript using the `document` object's `URL` property:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (document.URL !== 'https://<your URL here>') {
        var _smartsupp = _smartsupp || {};
        _smartsupp.key = '123456789';
        window.smartsupp ||
            (function (d) {
                var s,
                    c,
                    o = (smartsupp = function () {
                        o._.push(arguments);
                    });
                o._ = [];
                s = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                c = d.createElement('script');
                c.type = 'text/javascript';
                c.charset = 'utf-8';
                c.async = true;
                c.src = 'https://www.smartsuppchat.com/loader.js?';
                s.parentNode.insertBefore(c, s);
            })(document);
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thnak you! This helped me a lot. Thanks for the better knowledge for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

`if (window.location.pathname !== '/X1XY') { // your code here }`

Comment: Pefect Victor! Thank you. I have a one question. My location is /X1XY/ + ID - How add all website starting with X1XY? With any ID? So that the code is functional for /X1XY/123 and /X1XY/321? Thnaks!

Comment: If ID is a query parameter, this is not possible with `window.location.pathname`. However with a path parameter it is possible and you will need to have a more dynamic check using something like regex.

Comment: You can replace `window.location.pathname !== '/X1XY'` to `window.location.pathname.includes('/X1XY')`